# Nodemailer error connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

In a process I receive data from a request and save it to a database, after verifying that it was saved I make an internal request to send the mail and pass some parameters to generate a PDF file to be attached.

En un proceso recibo datos de una petición y los guardo a una base de datos, tras verificar que se guardó hago un request interno para hacer el envió del correo y la paso unos parámetros para generar un archivo PDF para ser adjuntado.

Configuración

```
var transporter    = nodemailer.createTransport({
//service: 'Gmail',
host:'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
    user: 'juanvilu',
    pass:  'password_correcto'
},
logger: bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'nodemailer'
}),
debug: true // include SMTP traffic in the logs
```

});

Salidas en consola

```
{"name":"nodemailer","hostname":"D00-8039H02","pid":6032,"level":50,"msg":"Send Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 108.177.9.108:465","time":"2017-02-24T23:05:19.768Z","v":0}

{"name":"nodemailer","hostname":"D00-8039H02","pid":6032,"level":50,"msg":"Send Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 108.177.9.108:465","time":"2017-02-24T23:05:19.768Z","v":0}
```

Comment: Looks like the destination is blocked - try TLS on port 587 instead?

Comment: or try this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Also https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Comment: There was nothing listening at port 465. Check your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was due to an unrecognized dns of a request coming from the internal call using a domain name that does not recognize port 3001 and I think that when trying to force the nodemailer driver it showed the connection error rejected by gmail being a False positive, but thank you very much for the comments